# Mocking session.createCriteria(XYZ.class) with JMockit in hiberate

Tags: hibernate, api, criteria, jmockit

I am using Jmockit version 1.8. When I try to to do:

@Mocked 
   Criteria criteria**; at class level at top, Junit throws an error:

Code:

```
 @Mocked
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Mocked
    Session session;

    @Mocked
    Transaction transaction;
    @Mocked
    Query query;

    @Mocked 
   Criteria criteria;
@Test
    public void getAllTransformationTest(){
        new NonStrictExpectations() {
            {
                sessionFactory.openSession();
                returns(session);

                session.createCriteria((Class) any);
                returns(criteria);
                criteria.add((SimpleExpression) any);

                criteria.list();
                returns(transformationCore.getListOfTransformations());

                session.close();
            }
        };

        List<TransformationResponse> result = transformation.getAllTransformation();
        assertTrue(result.size() > 0);
    }
```

Any one has the solution to mock hibernate criteria Api. How can i do it?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at mockit.internal.util.ConstructorReflection.newInstanceUsingDefaultConstructor(ConstructorReflection.java:166)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.createNewMockInstanceFactoryForInterface(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:118)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.createMockedInterfaceImplementationAndInstanceFactory(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:84)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineType(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:55)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.TypeRedefinition.redefineType(TypeRedefinition.java:47)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.SharedFieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineTypeForMockField(SharedFieldTypeRedefinitions.java:60)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldType(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:48)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldTypes(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:38)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.SharedFieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineTypesForTestClass(SharedFieldTypeRedefinitions.java:43)
    at mockit.integration.internal.TestRunnerDecorator.handleMockFieldsForWholeTestClass(TestRunnerDecorator.java:110)
    at mockit.integration.internal.TestRunnerDecorator.updateTestClassState(TestRunnerDecorator.java:32)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.handleMockingOutsideTestMethods(JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.java:104)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.invokeExplosively(JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.java:36)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(MockFrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:112)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.j
```

Comment: Please add your code that is doing the action throwin this exception - otherwise it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to mock data objects, especially those with very wide APIs (like Criteria). Is there a reason you need to use mocks rather than real objects?

Comment: James I have updated the code. All I want is to mock   Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Transformation.class);

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("isDeleted", IS_DELETED));

        List<Transformation> transList = crit.list();
Mock this code and return the mocked instance..

Comment: Jeff I donot want any real call to go into database for my unit testing so I would like to mock all dao layer and return mocked instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find the solution using below API. Instead of Mocking Criteria api, Create the real object of Criteria API, then pass this object as a parameter to nonStrictExpectation API argument and mock the subsequent calls made from criteria API as below example:

@Mocked SessionImplementor sessionImplementor;

final Criteria cr  =   new CriteriaImpl("YourClassName", sessionImplementor);

```
new NonStrictExpectations(cr) {
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            returns(session);
            session.createCriteria((Class) any);
            returns(cr);
            cr.list();
            returns(getListOfInstance());
        }
    };

    List<MyClass> data = obj.getList(params);
    assertTrue(data.size() > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but could not reproduce the failure. The following simplified (but functionally equivalent) version of the test works fine for me:

```
@Mocked SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Mocked Criteria criteria;

@Test
public void exampleTestMockingHibernateCriteriaAPI() {
    final List<String> expectedResults = asList("ab", "cde");
    new Expectations() {{ criteria.list(); result = expectedResults; }};

    // From the code under test:
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(String.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("tst", 123));
    List<?> result = c.list();

    assertEquals(expectedResults, result);
}
```